# Laravel 8 auth Attempting and Failed events not firing as expected

Tags: laravel, authentication, events, fortify, laravel-jetstream

I'm at a loss here... I'm using Laravel 8 with the jetstream inertia stack. I've setup event listeners in my `EventServiceProvider` to log various authentication events but the events don't seem to fire as expected. `Login` and `Logout` both work as expected, but I can't figure out the logic behind `Attempting` and `Failed`. `Attempting` only seems to fire when I successfully login. If I pass an invalid email/password it never fires. And I can't seem to figure out when `Failed` ever fires. All I want to accomplish is logging attempts to login to my system, even if they are providing invalid credentials.

Here's my EventServiceProvider. All the listeners are very simple with just a line to log a message in the `handle()` method.

```php
    protected $listen = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting::class => [
            \App\Listeners\Auth\LogAttemptingLogin::class
        ],
        \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login::class => [
            \App\Listeners\Auth\LogSuccessfulLogin::class,
        ],
        \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout::class => [
            \App\Listeners\Auth\LogSuccessfulLogout::class,
        ],
        \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed::class => [
            \App\Listeners\Auth\LogFailedLogin::class,
        ]
];
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same issues with exact same stack. It feels like LogFailedLogin not triggering is a bug or something.

I opened an issue as I'm having an hunch that it has to do with Fortify: https://github.com/laravel/fortify/issues/145.

Edit: It's a confirmed bug at the time of writing.

Comment: Thanks for submitting the bug report! I still haven't gotten this resolved. I'll keep an eye on your issue and try to update the post once there's a solution.

Comment: It got fixed and merged, composer update should do the trick.